# Showing a landscape UIViewController in a portrait UITabBarController/UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I understand that this question (or variations of it) has been asked quite a few times, however it's still how to best approach this problem without delving into kludgy hacks.

I have an application with the following layout:

```
UITabBarController
  ↳ UINavigationController
      ↳ PortraitViewController
          ↳ LandscapeViewController
```

The first `PortraitViewController` has its `rightBarButtonItem` set to a `UIBarButtonItem`, which calls `landscapeButtonPressed:`. That method pushes the `LandscapeViewController` onto the view controller stack.

In `LandscapeViewController`, I set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` during initialisation, since I only want the navigation bar visible.

I also call `setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` on `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in `loadView` and `viewWillAppear:`, and then set it back in to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` in `viewWillDisappear:`.

In my `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` implementation, I return YES only for `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.

The `PortraitViewController` looks like this:

[Portrait View http://img.skitch.com/20091007-18ur7p3iubkrb1if5cak8wdxkb.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091007-18ur7p3iubkrb1if5cak8wdxkb.png)

The `LandscapeViewController` looks like this:

[Broken Landscape View http://img.skitch.com/20091007-f3ki1ga5m4ytkyg3wgwektp86e.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091007-f3ki1ga5m4ytkyg3wgwektp86e.png)

As you can see, the view is not rotating correctly. If I call the private `-[UIDevice setOrientation:]` method before I call `-[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:]`, I can get the navigation bar to rotate properly, but I'd rather not be calling private methods and there doesn't seem to be a way to get the bounds of my main view for laying out subviews. Using the private method results in this:

[Better Landscape View http://img.skitch.com/20091007-8ckbx6gpbiateju9qjgew4x3k2.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091007-8ckbx6gpbiateju9qjgew4x3k2.png)

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

My goal is to have a view in landscape orientation, with valid landscape CGRect coordinates that I can use as the basis for laying out subviews.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan,

I feel that you have set PortraitViewController as the rootViewController of UINavigationController. I also believe that you are restricting the PortraitViewController's orientation only to UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait only in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method. If so then, any view controller that you push will have the orientation of the rootViewController itself unless you are not changing the device orientation by rotating your device.

So if you need the LandscapeViewController in the UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight orientation then just allow this in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and don't screw things by explicitly setting the device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

The LandscapeViewController is not automatically rotating because `interfaceOrientation` is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`, so you have to return YES  for `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`

To have your views resizing correctly you have to open your xib file with Interface Builder, then into the Inspector and finally into the tab "Size".

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm already returning `YES` for in the landscape controller.

Comment: I was sure you had write `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` instead of `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` ...
My mistake.